# лямбда-выражения в качестве компаратора

Tags: c++, сортировка, stl, лямбда-выражение, контейнеры

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
};
```

```
list <MyClass> l1;
```

в словаре m1: ключ = уникальное имя(которое FirstName), его значение = кол-во вхождений в списке l1

```
map<string, int> m1;
```

сортирую список l1 по частоте имён, подставляя в качестве компаратора следующее лямбда-выражение:

```
auto lx = [&m1](const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b)
    {
        return m1[a.FirstName]> m1[b.FirstName];
    };
sort(l1.begin(), l1.end(),lx);
```

компилятор ругается трижды(все по поводу файла algorithm)
1. Ошибка   C2676   бинарный "-": "const std::_List_unchecked_iterator>>" не определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному оператору
2. Ошибка   C2672   "_Sort_unchecked": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция
3. Ошибка   C2780   void std::_Sort_unchecked(_RanIt,_RanIt,iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type,_Pr): требует аргументов: 4, имеется: 3

вроде как, кажется, проблема в передаче параметров в само лямбда-выражение? как

Answer (score 0):

Компаратор и лямбда-выражение тут совсем ни при чем.

`std::sort` неприменим к `std::list` вообще. `std::sort` работает только с итераторами *произвольного доступа*. Итераторы `std::list` - итераторы *последовательного доступа* (двунаправленные).

Для `std::list` используйте его собственный метод сортировки

```
l1.sort(lx);
```